# PrimeNG Turbotable active my filter on init

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Since PrimeNG Datatable is deprecated, I upgraded in TurboTable and I need when my component (or the view) is init to active my filter. It works with Datatable but not with my turbotable. I'm using ChangeDetectorRef to detectChanges.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.setFilters();
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Call table.filter() instead of using ChangeDetectorRef**

```
export class DynamicDataTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(Table) table: Table;

  columns = [
    { field: 'name', header: 'Name' }
  ];

  records = [
    { name: '123 Should display' },
    { name: '321 Should not display' }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    // Set Filters
    this.table.filters = {
      name: { value:'123', matchMode: 'contains' }
    };
    this.table.filter(null, null, null);
  }

}
```